# Regex for digits and space as thousand separator

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

This regex should allow me to input numbers with space as thousand separator, but some how it is accepting alphabets and special characters too. Can someone help me with what is wrong with the regex:

```
reg = new RegExp("^(?:\s*([0-9]* [0-9]{3})\s*)*$||[0-9]*");
```

Comment: This regex matches any string. What pattern do you need to match? Please provide some input to test against, explain what result you need to get.

Comment: post your input for match

Comment: Inputs can be like  Valid : "3000" "3 000" "3 000 000"

Comment: Invalid ones are : any special character or alphabet

Comment: You seem to need `var rx = /^\d+(?: \d{3})*$/;`, please let me know if [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/bw9e6oqm/1/) works for you. If you need to support leading/trailing whitespaces, add `\s*` after `^` and before `$`.

Comment: it should fail for "3000 000"

Answer (score 2):

The grouping of OR seems incorrect (also, use `|`, not `||`).

Try this

```
   new RegExp(
    "^("  //start of line
    + "(?:" // number with thousands separator
      + "[0-9]{1,3}" //1..3 digits once 
      + "(?: [0-9]{3})*?" //exactly 3 digits, preceded by space, any number of times
    + ")"
    + "|(?:" // or just number 
      + "[0-9]+" //any number of digits without spaces
    + ")"
    + ")$");
```

Depending or your needs, you can allow or reject non-three digit parts.

Comment: Your pattern validates `3000 000` which is invalid, and it does not validate `3 000 000`, which is valid

Comment: it works only  problem is that it allows spaces in the start and in the end.

Comment: Just remove \\s* at the start and at the end (from your sample I assumed it is a requirement). I did edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can greatly simplify that regex.

```
^[0-9 ]+$
```

This matches numbers with or without spaces as a separator.  However, note that it will match on a space anywhere (not only as a thousands separator).  It should be easy enough to tweak though.

Edit:  Here's another alternative that forces spaces to separate thousands in the number.

```
^[0-9]{1,3}()\s?([0-9]{3}\s?)+$
```

Comment: I tested it with a couple of different inputs.

Comment: What input does it fail on?